# Custom Django count filtering

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-filter

A lot of websites will display:

- "1.8K pages" instead of "1,830 pages"

or

- "43.2M pages" instead of "43,200,123 pages"

Is there a way to do this in Django?

For example, the following code will generate the quantified amount of objects in the queryset (i.e. 3,123):

```
Books.objects.all().count()
```

Is there a way to add a custom count filter to return "3.1K pages" instead of "3,123 pages?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you looking to change what the actual queryset returns? Or just have that displayed on your page? They are two totally different things.

Comment: I'd look at the `intword` built in filter. It doesn't do exactly what you're asking for, since it leaves numbers under one million unchanged and uses the full word rather than `K`, `M`, etc, but it would be a good starting point for a custom filter. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py

Comment: @electrometro Which is easier to implement? I'm assuming changing the response of queryset would be the better long term goal, but for now simply displaying it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I wouldn't do anything that alters the way the ORM portion of Django works. There are two places this could be done, if you are only planning on using it in one place - do it on the frontend. With that said, there are many ways to achieve this result. Just to spout off a few ideas, you could write a property on your model that calls count then converts that to something a little more  human readable for the back end. If you want to do it on the frontend you might want to find a JavaScript lib that could do the conversion.

I will edit this later from my computer and add an example of the property.

Edit: To answer your comment, the easier one to implement depends on your skills in python vs in JavaScript. I prefer python so I would probably do it in there somewhere on the model.

Edit2: I have wrote an example to show you how I would do a `classmethod` on a base model or on the model that you need these numbers on. I found a python package called [humanize](https://github.com/jmoiron/humanize) and I took its function that converts these to readable and modified it a bit to allow for thousands and took out some of the super large number conversion.

```
def readable_number(value, short=False):
    # Modified from the package `humanize` on pypy.
    powers = [10 ** x for x in (3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18)]
    human_powers = ('thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion', 'quadrillion')
    human_powers_short = ('K', 'M', 'B', 'T', 'QD')
    try:
        value = int(value)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return value

    if value < powers[0]:
        return str(value)
    for ordinal, power in enumerate(powers[1:], 1):
        if value < power:
            chopped = value / float(powers[ordinal - 1])
            chopped = format(chopped, '.1f')
            if not short:
                return '{} {}'.format(chopped, human_powers[ordinal - 1])
            return '{}{}'.format(chopped, human_powers_short[ordinal - 1])


class MyModel(models.Model):
    @classmethod
    def readable_count(cls, short=True):
        count = cls.objects.all().count()
        return readable_number(count, short=short)


print(readable_number(62220, True))  # Returns '62.2K'
print(readable_number(6555500))  # Returns '6.6 million'
```

I would stick that `readable_number` in some sort of utils and just import it in your models file. Once you have that, you can just stick that string wherever you would like on your frontend.

You would use `MyModel.readable_count()` to get that value. If you want it under `MyModel.objects.readable_count()` you will need to make a custom object manager for your model, but that is a bit more advanced.